# Calculate each day hours in GanttChart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Formula is for calculating costs in Gantt Chart that is for two years from this date. I have made two worksheets: one where user inputs data (GanttChart) and another one where values are calculated (Calculation). I have to copy formula to 44835 cells on Calculation worksheet so the whole range would be covered.

**Sample of my data:**

- Weekdays on top - MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU (Gantt Chart goes for 2 years)
- Working time - 1-24 hours
- Working cost - 50
- Working time is inputted to P10:ABC100 (11 hours on the screenshot)

**Calculation (example below with 11 hours a day):**

If it is MO, TU, WE, TH, FR and Working time is <= 8 hours -> 8*50
-> if Working time is > 8 hours 8*50+((11-8)-(11-10))*(1+50%)+((11-10)*(1+100%))

If it is SA and Working time is <= 8 hours -> 8*50
-> if Working time is > 8 hours 8*50*(1+50%)+((11-8)-(11-10))*(1+100%)

If it is SU and previous days in a week COUNT is 6 (This means if person has been working previous 6 days before Sunday = Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa) -> Sunday hours*(1+300%)*50 -> Sunday hours*(1+200%)*50

**Question:**

Is it possible to do calculation for the whole row in the end of calendar

Here is what I have tried but ended up in massive Excel calculation that gets Excel stuck:

Comment: Please attach your file

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin added

Comment: have you look this variant? https://www.ganttexcel.com/

Comment: Why "copy" the formula? Ifr you use the relative and absolute referencing correctly (covered in your question on the 31st), then if you select all the cells and enter the first formula in the top leftmost cell, you can enter all the formulae by using ctrl+enter.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin this looks advanced. The only problem is to get there all these overwork percentages

Comment: if you fill 44835 cells with formulas it would be really bad idea, as you book will be very slow

Comment: Why do this in excel? there are many (free and paid) project management software that are available with myriads of functions... If you insist on excel, then use vba to do the calculations and paste values...

Comment: Another idea was to input these formulas to VBA and input them on Worksheet_calculate to corresponding cell on another Worksheet

Comment: @SolarMike there is already another Excel created to calculate all the other project costs and print out documents in Word format. So this is more like a program already. Idea was to connect them together

Comment: What is GanttChart!$C11 and GanttChart!$D11 and GanttChart!$E11 it is bonus? What is GanttChart!$K11 it is 8hour price?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin GanttChart!$C11 and GanttChart!$D11 and GanttChart!$E11 are for different employee groups. There are 3 of them so I would like to separate them. GanttChart!$K11 is just a daily allowance, it is calculated separately (can be skipped).

Comment: your formula is wrong  as `MAX(0;GanttChart!Q11-8)-MAX(0;GanttChart!Q11-10)<0` always will be >0

Comment: It was basically to display only positive results. So if it will be negative, it will give 0. I had IF there before but then was trying to get rid of IF's and tested with MAX

Comment: in wich case it can be negative? and did not found any variant and always it equal 2. So please explain in word each counting

Comment: We need to test for these 2 hours out of each day amount. So basically if work is 8 hours a day (MO, TU, WE, TH, FR) then it is simply 8*cost. If it is 9 hours it is 8*cost + one 50% extra hour cost. If it is 10 hours a day then 8*cost + two 50% extra hour cost. If it is 11 hours a day then 8*cost + two extra hour cost 50% + one extra hour cost 100%. **Then** if we have 9 hours a day `(GanttChart!Q11-8)-(GanttChart!Q11-10)` will return to (9-8)-(9-10) = 2 it should be 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194420/discussion-between-dmitrij-holkin-and-user7202022).